# Check if data is stationary using adfuller

Tags: python, machine-learning, statsmodels

#check if data is stationary

```
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller

from numpy import log

result = adfuller(data.value.dropna())

print('p-value: %f' % result[1])
```

Trying to get the p value for finding if the data is stationary but getting an error that says

```
'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'value'
```

reference:https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/06/random-forest-for-time-series-forecasting/

Comment: given example from the reference website, its not clear jeans_data is the df or not. try jeans_data as data and validate it with the result p-value

Comment: It is `data.values` no `data.value` to get the NumPy array in the `DataFrame`.  Ot use `data.to_numpy()`. FWIW you don't need to use this and `adfuller(data.dropna())` should work as long as `data` has a single column.